# Two-dimensional Two-particle system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, two-level-system

I have to find the energy levels of a two dimensional system with two energy eigenstates $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ with energies $E_0$ and $E_1$. Furthermore there are two noninteracting particles $a$ and $b$. The Hamiltonian of this system is:

$H^0$=$H_a$+$H_b$

where the subscript stands for particle $a$ and $b$. I tried to calculate the matrix elements of $H^0$ but I have a problem with the fact that we have two particles. For one particle the matrix elements would just be given by $\langle i|H^0|j \rangle$. But how does this work for two particles? My idea is to start with the state for particle $a$ and $b$ as following:

$|\psi_a\rangle$=$a_1|0\rangle$+$a_2|1\rangle$

$|\psi_b\rangle$=$b_1|0\rangle$+$b_2|1\rangle$

The combined wavefunction would then be given by the tensor product of $|\psi_a\rangle$ and $|\psi_b\rangle$. But from here I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You are told both $H_a$ and $H_b$ are simultaneously diagonalizable to diag($E_0,E_1$) in their respective bases. So the full hamiltonian diagonalizes to the 4x4 matrix
$$
H^0= \operatorname{diag}(E_0,E_1) \otimes \mathbb{I} +   \mathbb{I}\otimes  \operatorname{diag}(E_0,E_1) \\
= \operatorname{diag}(E_0+E_0,E_0+E_1,E_1+E_0, E_1+E_1 ) $$
in tensor product notation, if you insist; with evident eigenvalues $2E_0$, $E_0+ E_1$, and $2E_1$, the middle one doubly degenerate.